# How can I find out that an Org Agenda file had been opened with 'inhibited startup'?

Tags: org-mode, start-up, find-file

My Emacs is opening the Agenda file in the background with `org-agenda-inhibit-startup` locally bound to `t`. When I switch to such a file, all trees are therefore displayed open (no folding).

I would like to add a function to `find-file-hook` which recognizes that this file has been opened in this restricted way and then applies all the functions which are usually called when opening an Org mode file.

My question thus refers to the first step: How can I recognize the state of such a file programmatically? I only want to call this repair function once, if I switch to the associated buffer the first time. I was thinking there might be some local variable which is missing when using `org-agenda-inhibit-startup`, or maybe there's some way to figure out that a file had been loaded, but only in the background.

Comment: Are you setting `org-inhibit-startup` yourself? If so, don't do that: it's a dynamically scoped variable that is used internally by Org mode. Setting it yourself will cause problems. Also, when you say "Agenda file", what exactly are you talking about? Perhaps the files that contribute to the agenda, i.e. what `org-agenda-files` returns? Maybe what you are looking for is `org-agenda-inhibit-startup`? If so, why? Does your agenda generation take too long?

Comment: You are right, I missed the "agenda" :) I'm binding `org-agenda-inhibit-startup` temporally while calling the agenda because I have more than 30 files. It really speeds things up.